# Detect \n in BufferedReader stream

Tags: java, bufferedreader, linefeed

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
"foobar\n"
```

I read this string using a BufferedReader. I need to be able to detect whether or not there is a new line present. I was using readLine, but I switched to read so I could grab the \n but no luck.

Comment: this post might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113435/how-to-find-out-which-line-separator-bufferedreaderreadline-used-to-split-the

Comment: Define "no luck". Using `read` will return the newline character, so something else in your code must be causing the problem you are seeing.

Comment: I was pushing all chars from read into an array and didn't see the \n in the array. I see it now, I was using the wrong read function. THanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and it works:

```
while((charT = reader.read()) != -1) {
if(charT != '\n')
System.out.println("Carriage Return!");
}
```