# Testing for unseen characters in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, carriage-return

I'm writing a program in Java that tests the validity of several FTP commands. These commands must in a a carriage return and new line feed (the sequence "\r\n"). I'm using a BufferedReader to read in lines, but I cannot come up with a way to check if the line ends in this sequence. Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113435/how-to-find-out-which-line-separator-bufferedreaderreadline-used-to-split-the

Comment: What have you tired? Show us your code.

Comment: If you want to check the exact sequence of CRLF you will need to read one char at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the `BufferedReader` because abstraction level seems too high for your specific tasks. Use the ordinary [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), and read into byte array. InputStream will read all bytes as they are. You can process them and later produce strings yourself later using [new String(array, offset, length)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29). Maybe it can be other invalid characters like 0x0C in the input.