# BufferedReader messed up by different line seperators

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm having a buffered reader streaming a file. There are two cases right now:

It is streaming a file generated on one PC, let's call it File1.
It is streaming a file generated on another Computer, let's call it File2.

I'm assuming my problem is caused by the EOLs.

BufferedReader does read both files, but for the File2, **it reads an extra empty line for every new line.**

Also, when I compare the line using `line.equalsIgnoreCase("abc")`, given that the line is `"abc"` **it does not return true.**

Use this code together with the two files provided in the two links to **replicate** the problem:

```
public class JavaApplication {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("C:/Users/User/Downloads/html (2).htm");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
    String line = "";

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

[File1](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=&confirm=no_antivirus&id=0B0iNx1MN3N2QRndtLWJYTDZsR3M),
[File2](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=&confirm=no_antivirus&id=0B0iNx1MN3N2QRlNveHlfbFBoTnM)

Note how the second file prints **an empty line after each line...**

I've been searching and trying and searching and trying, and couldn't come up with a solution.

Any ideas how to fix that? (Especially the compare thing?)

Comment: I think there is a mix-up between `\r`, CR, 0x0d and `\n`, LF, 0x0a. Because if lines were ending on `\n\r` instead, BufferedReader would recognize two lines: ending in `\n` = Unix style, and `\r` = old Mac style, whereas `\r\n` would have been Windows style.

Comment: Well, it would make more sense if `\r\n` would make it read an empty line every other line, but it's `\r` that's doing that... 
I used this answer to find out the separator, maybe it is not fully functional either ^^ http://stackoverflow.com/a/13828045/3653975

Comment: @JoopEggen yet what is the problem? Updated answer to show the code I use to get the new line, and also to compare the lines... Help is much appreciated

Comment: You could try `line = line.replaceAll("\r\n","\n");`

Comment: @SaviourSelf that wouldn't help anything as the line comes from the bufferedReader, so I cannot replace anything prior to reading it line by line ;)

Comment: @Maverick283 Are the file contents too large to hold in memory? Can you read the entire file contents into a `StringBuilder()` ?

Comment: @SaviourSelf both files are almost equal in size... Since one works and the smaller one doesn't this shouldn't affect the result either...

Comment: The first shows UTF-8, the other UTF-16. UTF-16 erroneaously read as UTF-8 for ASCII contains a nul byte (char) after every byte (char).  **That is the solution.** It is also specified as such in the HTML, charset=...

Comment: @JoopEggen But both files have `charset=UTF-16`, don't they? Yet that would explain why a Levenshtein returned big values when I tried to compare the two...

Comment: Yes, but the sizes are very different, and you are reading them as UTF-8. One should read them probably as UTF-16LE, My program's editor Kate detected UTF-8 for the small, UTF-16LE for the larger one. A small test would be to do `line = line.replace("\u0000", "");`

Comment: Ohhh I see where you're coming from... Yeah, that UTF-8 thing happened when I tried to get them uploaded... The originals are both the same encoding though...

Comment: I must go to bed ;) - maybe do a hex dump or such. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joop was right, after some more research it seems like, even though both files have specified a UTF-16 encoding in their header, one was encoded in UTF-16, and the other (File1) in UTF-8. This lead to the "double line effect". 
Thanks for the effort that was put in answering this question.

Comment: I believe you can mark your own answer as correct.  You should do that if this was the actual answer.

Comment: I was gonna do that but you need to wait one day until your able to do so ;) Thanks again for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Works for me.

```
public class CRTest
{
   static StringReader test = new StringReader( "Line 1\rLine 2\rLine 3\r" );
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader( test );
      for( String line = null; (line = buf.readLine()) != null; )
         System.out.println( line );
   }
}
```

Prints:

```
run:
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

As Joop said, I think you've mixed up which file isn't working.  Please use the above skeleton to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us exactly what file input isn't working for you.

---

Since you appear to have a file with reversed `\r\n` lines, here's my first attempt at a fix.  Please test it, I haven't tried it yet.  You need to wrap your `InputStreamReader` with this class, then wrap the `BufferedReader` on the outside like normal.

```
class CRFix extends Reader
{

   private final Reader reader;
   private boolean readNL = false;

   public CRFix( Reader reader ) {
      this.reader = reader;
   }

   @Override
   public int read( char[] cbuf, int off, int len )
           throws IOException
   {
      for( int i = off; i < off+len; i++ ) {
         int c = reader.read();
         if( c == -1 )
            if( i == off ) return -1;
            else return i-off-1;
         if( c == '\r' && readNL ) { 
            readNL = false;
            c = reader.read();
         }
         if( c == '\n' ) 
            readNL = true;
         else 
            readNL = false;
         cbuf[i] = (char)c;
      }
      return len;
   }

   @Override
   public void close()
           throws IOException
   {
      reader.close();
   }

}
```

Comment: Alright, I guess the method i used to figure out which one uses which returns an inverse result... Not sure though. Assuming it actually IS the other way around, how do I get it to read only one line rather then two when the line seperator is `\r\n`?

Comment: I've (finally) updated my question with a sample, hope it does what it is supposed to do...

Comment: I tested the CRFix class and I fixed how I detect end of file.  It should work now.  But as you mention the files you posted don't have the problem you describe.  It's likely your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: There we go, try File2 again, it downloads and replicates the problem, with and without CRFix using the code provided in my question